# operation not permitted error on Linux Python

Tags: python, linux, shutil

I am using shutil copy to copy the text file from one location to other. But it is throwing exception:

> Operation not permitted.

But surprisingly I can see that the file is copied to destination folder. Then why it is throwing exception? I am using below code.

```py
import shutil
old_name='/test/test1.txt'
new_name='/test1/test1.txt'
try:
        shutil.copy(old_name, new_name)
except IOError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using sudo?
If you use /sudo rest_of_command it should stop giving you the error.
Using sudo can be dangerous so only use it if you feel confident and know what you are doing.

Comment: It is through application user, so can't do sudo.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. Is the error causing the program to crash?

Comment: No it is not crashing but going into exception block. I have exception handling and failing the application.